# Find all possible query string values with python

Tags: python, parsing, query-string

I'm trying to figure out how to parse a website that doesn't have documentation available to explain the query string. I am wondering if there is a way to get all possible valid values for different fields in a query string using Python.

For example, let's say I have the current URL that I wish to parse:

`http://www.website.com/stat?field1=a&field2=b`

Is there a way to find all of the possible values for field1 that return information? Let's say that field1 of the qs can take either values "a" or "z" and I do not know it can take value "z". Is there a way to figure out that "z" is the only other value that is possible in that field without any prior knowledge?

Comment: You can use trial & error, obviously. But that's about it.

Comment: Well, all possible values will return "some" information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the website itself. If it has other values of field1 or field2, you can only know that by looking into the code or documentation(if available). That's the only accurate way of knowing it. Otherwise, you can try brute forcing (trying all possible alphanumeric values Ever), but that doesn't guaranty anything. In that case you'll need a way to know which values are valid and which are not. Hardly efficient.